# Can i create an old version of Azure Mobile Web Service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have some pre-existing Azure Mobile Services, these were written when they were using `request.service.mssql.query()` when running a custom sql statement. However since then Azure has updated their mobile services to instead use `req.azureMobile.data.execute()`

I need to create a new Azure Mobile Service that connects to another database. This new service uses very similar calls to the existing services I already have running.

Is there a way for me to create a new Azure Mobile Service that is using the old method? Because if I must use the new method I will have to re-write the calls which is a lot of work as there are lots of calls.

If I must use the new method, is there a fast way to convert the pre-existing calls to the new method?

Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to create an [Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop) (new Azure Mobile Service) and then use the old Node.js backend SDK?

Comment: Would that enable me to use the code that i have written in the old mobile service?

Comment: Azure Mobile Apps uses this SDK: [azure-mobile-apps-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node). Maybe you can try to replace this SDK with [the old SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services-node) for your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [compatibility NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-mobile-apps-compatibility) to allow your Mobile Service scripts to run in a Mobile App. It also requires a view of your database with different system column names for the createdAt, updatedAt and deleted columns. Or if you don't have an existing Mobile Service using the old column names, you can just rename the columns (remove the __ prefixes).

The Azure documentation has a more complete [page on upgrading your Mobile Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-upgrading-from-mobile-services) using this NPM.